# Find proxyaddress:port in Windows

Tags: windows, proxy, git, environment-variables, http

I try to set the proxy when I work in companies so use git; pip freely. Currently I know that I need to set the proxy because when I try to `pip install` a certain library I get the old message :

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DB49235280>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/holidays/

My default way was:

1. Find the proxy ports using in cmd:

   `netsh winhttp show proxy`
2. Go on the envs variables and set the http and https proxies:

   `http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port`

However is the first time when I run step 1 and I get the following message from netsh:

> Current WinHTTP proxy settings: Direct access (no proxy server).

How do I find the proxyaddress:port at this point ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I don't have server:port part @harrymc . The question is about how to find that part

Comment: @harrymc I would like to define in it in the env variables but I don't know what my server and port is. I don't know how to find that specific part. And then I will do it as always http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port

Comment: @harrymc that is the general way to set the http proxies in your envs variables on windows. You knew already the form with your first comment ending with server:port

Comment: @harrymc as I said, that is the general way of setting a proxy, I didn't invent the format, that's how it works. I am attempting to use a proxy, because the pc that I currently uses blocks the outside connections via an automatic script adress proxy

Comment: example : https://askubuntu.com/questions/82880/how-do-i-set-a-system-wide-proxy-with-a-username-and-password @harrymc

Comment: Sorry, there is some misunderstanding here about the nature of a proxy. I suggest to use the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/), since it comes with its own proxy built-in. Be careful where you download it from.

Comment: @harrymc thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Please read [What is a proxy server and how does it work?](https://www.javatpoint.com/what-is-a-proxy-server-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you are working in a company and `pip` and `git` does not work.

You are now looking for a proxy to make them work.

But **buying a proxy**, VPN or using tor won't help. The reason is shown in the output of pip:

```
... HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DB49235280>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out
```

Now if HTTPs connections are blocked it's very unlikely that **buying a proxy**, VPN or tor will help.

Maybe there is a proxy (web washer) that has to be used in your network. For example if you have a web browser that is able to access the internet you can look into the browser's proxy settings to get the ip/port.

If this didn't help you have to ask your network administrator for internet. He will tell you the necessary configuration.

Comment: Found a semi solution. In the .dat file found the rerouting with the server:port. Replaced that to the environement variables and it worked. Now I can, git clone and everything. In addition to the pip install, I just added the trusted websites and deactivated the sslCertfication validation.  @zomega

Comment: @minattosama You didn't tell us anything about a .dat file. It was impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I found on a site that if you access the .dat file of your pc, you might find it. Is not that I had a .dat file hidden from you. Every pc has that in the browser (Edge, Chrome etc)

Comment: @minattosama There are thousands of .dat files on a Windows PC. Which .dat file are you talking about? What is the path?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not an expert to explain in details but searching in internet I found that using the WPAD.dat you can get that information. And I just found the way to find that WPAD.dat in my pc (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol)